# create a variable from geojson properties keys

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, geojson

i have a geojson file using into an html map.
i need to create a var from some properties of this geojson and use it with javascript.

my geojson is like the one below, I have saved it in .js type and include it into a var called geojson:

```js
var geojson={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "mygeojson",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "a": 1, "b": "0101", "c": 211790.00031900001, "d": 646919770.72243118, "e": "1", "f": "01", "g": "h", "i": 66919, "j": 65323, "k": 1596, "l": 673, "m": 923 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ 25.567629302477478, 41.31758701241241 ], [ 25.567891303197911, 41.317582422728094 ], [ 25.567440555663143, 41.317611968065137 ], [ 25.567629302477478, 41.31758701241241 ] ] } }
]
}
```

what i need is to create a var like this: var x = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]
or even to create a var and give to it every time a different value between a and m, probably using if.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution and it was sth like that:

var z = Object.keys(geojson["features"][0].properties);